# Why am I getting a compilation warning when converting a unichar to a string in vala?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, vala

Here is a short program to demonstrate the issue:

```
void main(string[] args)
{
    unichar c = 'a';
    string str_from_to_string = c.to_string(); // Warning
    stdout.printf("Converted by unichar.to_string: \"%s\"\n", str_from_to_string);
}
```

This also causes the same warning:

```
void main(string[] args)
{
    unichar c = 'a';
    string str_from_template = @"$c"; // Warning
    stdout.printf("Converted by string template: \"%s\"\n", str_from_template);
}
```

This is the warning that I get:

```
/home/mpiroc/Desktop/unicode_to_string/unicode_to_string.vala.c: In function ‘g_unichar_to_string’:
/home/mpiroc/Desktop/unicode_to_string/unicode_to_string.vala.c:26:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘g_unichar_to_utf8’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gunicode.h:684:11: note: expected ‘gchar *’ but argument is of type ‘const gchar *’
```

And here is the generated c code mentioned in the warning:

```
 18 static gchar* g_unichar_to_string (gunichar self) {
 19     gchar* result = NULL;
 20     gchar* _tmp0_ = NULL;
 21     gchar* str;
 22     const gchar* _tmp1_;
 23     _tmp0_ = g_new0 (gchar, 7);
 24     str = (gchar*) _tmp0_;
 25     _tmp1_ = str;
 26     g_unichar_to_utf8 (self, _tmp1_);
 27     result = str;
 28     return result;
 29 }
```

It seems as though `_tmp_` probably should not be marked `const`, but this is generated by `valac`, not written directly by me. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in `valac`? The code functions as expected, but I try to avoid warnings when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add --disable-warnings command-line option](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2009-September/msg09183.html)

IIRC Vala compiler can also use --disable-warnigs command-line option.

Edit:

[gcc commandline options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Sorry, Valac is transpiler, so once valac --ccode output, and then 
need to run gcc or another compiler.

```
$ valac --ccode unicode_to_string.vala
$ gcc -o unicode_to_string -w unicode_to_string.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gobject-2.0`
```

Comment: You could also just do `valac -X -w -o unicode_to_string unicode_to_string.vala`.  --Xcc/-X will tell valac to pass the supplied argument to the CC.

Answer (score 1):

The Vala compiler does not make temporary variables `const`. You can safely ignore warnings about `const`-ness.

Comment: It doesn't? Then why is `_tmp1_` in the generated code `const`? It clearly is a temporary variable.

Comment: Err. Doesn't correctly make variables or parameters `const`. In this particular case, `g_unichar_to_string` is an instance method of `unichar`, but it does not mark the parameter `self` as `const`. Temporary variables that Vala is duplicating are `const`, because the compiler know it does not intend to modify them. That is what's causing the above error: the temporary copy of the `unichar` is made `const` while the instance method of `unichar.to_string()` is not marking `self` (i.e., the instance parameters) as `const`.

Comment: No that's not the problem. The problem is that the second argument to `g_unichar_to_utf8` is a non-const pointer (which makes sense since it is going to be modified), but the code is passing `_tmp1_` as an argument, which is a const pointer. So the problem isn't that valac forgot a const somewhere, it's that it added one where it doesn't belong.

Comment: This is where the Vala C type generator is buggy: the difference between a `const char *` and a `char const *`
It means the latter but prints the former. At any rate, most `const`-related warnings are safely ignored.